# Let $x-\frac 1x=\sqrt 2 i$. Then find the value of $x^{2187}-\frac{1}{x^{2187}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Solving the quadratic equation, we find x to be 
$$x=\frac{i \pm 1}{\sqrt 2}$$
Moving back to the original expression 
$$\frac{(x^2)^{2187}-1}{x^{2187}}$$
$$=\frac{-i-1}{x^{2187}}$$
I don’t know how to solve further

The answer is $\sqrt 2 i$

Comment: It is easy to take powers of a complex number written in polar form. $x=e^{\pi i/4}$

Comment: Compute $x^2.\phantom{}$

Comment: $x^2=i$ @anomaly I used it above

Comment: Tools become useful in the right hands.

Comment: Of course they do. But tools need to be taught to a mind for it to be used efficiently

Comment: @Aditya: So from that, compute $x^{2187} = x(x^2)^{2186/2}$.

Comment: $e^{i2187\pi/4}=(e^{2\pi i})^{273} e^{3i\pi/4}=1^{273}e^{3i\pi.4}=e^{3\pi i /4}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet it then gives $\frac{i}{\sqrt 2}$ in the denominator, but the addition symbol isn’t being eliminated in the numerator

Comment: I don't understand any of that... BTW, $1^{273}e^{3i\pi .4}$ should have been $1^{273}e^{3\pi i/4}.$ There were some now-deleted comments about the number $e^{i2187\pi /4}.$ This number is not the A to your posted Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the given as  $x^2-\sqrt 2 i x - 1=0$, which has the solution

$$ x = \frac{i\pm 1}{\sqrt2} = ie^{\pm i\frac\pi4}\implies x^{\pm 2187}=x^{\pm 3}$$

Thus,

$$x^{2187}-\frac1{x^{2187}}=x^{3}-\frac1{x^{3}}=\left(x-\frac1x\right)^3+3\left(x-\frac1x\right)=(\sqrt2 i)^3+3\sqrt2 i=\sqrt2 i$$

Comment: That's actually the best explanation I have seen so far, understood it in an instant. I always find your answers to be precise and easy to understand. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\left( \dfrac{i\pm1}{\sqrt2}\right)^8=1$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x=\pm\exp\frac{\pm\pi i}{4}$, $x^8=1$ and$$x^{2187}-x^{-2187}=x^3-x^{-3}=\pm\left(\exp\frac{\pm3\pi i}{4}-\exp\frac{\mp3\pi i}{4}\right)=2i\Im\exp\frac{3\pi i}{4}=i\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: Here is what I did. $\frac{-i-1}{e^{i3\pi/4}}$

Comment: $\frac{-i-1}{i.\frac {1}{\sqrt 2}}$

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt 2(-i-1)}{i}=\sqrt 2(1+i)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^{3^n}-x^{-3^n}=A_n.$ Then $(A_n)^3=A_{n+1}-3A_n.$ So if $A_n=i\sqrt 2$ then $A_{n+1}=i\sqrt 2=A_n.$ We are given $A_0=i\sqrt 2.$ Therefore $$i\sqrt 2=A_0=A_1=A_2=A_3=A_4=A_5=A_6=A_7=x^{2187}-x^{-2187}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$(x-1/x)^2=-2$$

$$\implies x^4+1=0,x^4=?$$

As $2187=594(4)-1,$

$x^{2187}=(x^4)^{594}x^{-1}=\cdots=\dfrac1x$